# NodeJS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, cors

My client (React app) and server (Node project) run on different ports. I'm trying to make an API request from the frontend to the backend, and am getting this error message in the frontend console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/period' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Relevant Project Info (updated)**

- Client Port: 3000
- Server Port: 5000
- Both the client and server URLs are simply localhost for now
- The client React project was set up using VITE.
- I am not currently using authentication in my React app, though I plan to later
- I am also not using a development proxy as of now
- The code where I define the API routes:

```
var mainRouter = require('express').Router();
const {getVersion, getPeriod} = require('../controllers/elementController');

mainRouter.get("/version", getVersion);
mainRouter.get("/period", getPeriod);

module.exports = mainRouter;
```

- This is how I'm making the API request with `axios` in my React code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}:${import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_PORT}/version`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("Versions:")
                console.log(res);
            });
}, []);
```

**Things I have tried (updated)**

- Installing the `cors` module and confirming that it is there
- Using `cors` like so in my NodeJS server's `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use("/", mainRouter);
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));
```

- I have also tried:

  - `app.use(cors({ origin: ['*'] }));`
  - `app.use(cors({ origin: 'localhost:3000' }));`
  - `app.use(cors({ origin: ['localhost:3000'] }));`.

All of these didn't seem to change anything even after restarting the client and server.

Comment: Try to specify allowed origins inside array instead of '*' ['https://some1.com', 'https://other.com',...]

Comment: Your question can't be answered. Please provide more information regarding your server and client. What is the server URL and what is the client URL. Are they both localhost or one of them is 127.0.0.1, what are the used ports? Are you using authentication in your React app or not? And are you using VITE or create-react-app or Next.js or what. And are you using a development proxy in your React app or not. This information is necessary in order to answer your question. It's a good question, but it lacks any good information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Just updated the original post with more information, please take a look if you can. Unfortunately using the array for allowed origins did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue - I accidentally put `app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));` before my router definition (`app.use("/", mainRouter);`). Switching their order fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are severel reasons that this error can be display.

- First make sure that the request url and the defined URL in the server is equal

For example if you defined localhost:3000/api/user and call it as localhost:3000/user then browser will display this error

- secondly make sure that you have installed used packages to install cors use npm i cors

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the URLs should be equal and I also made sure that cors is installed correctly. I just updated the original post with more info!

Comment: Did you try calling API with postman i notice some small issue here. you are using app(“/“,mainRouter) so change it to app(“/api”,mainRouter) and try calling api as http://localhost:5000/api/period i hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have `cors` is installed if not then install with :

```js
npm i cors
```

Then:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I have made sure that cors was installed correctly and have also tried using it as you mentioned. I just updated the original post with more info!